# Sourcemaps horribly broken using typescript and browserify/gulp

Tags: typescript, gulp, browserify, source-maps

I am successfully getting sourcemaps output from my build process which uses browserify with gulp. However, the sourcemaps don't work when debugging - breakpoints often jump to a different line when I set them (in Chrome), and it is clear the script is not actually pausing where it says it is. When I hover over variables to view their values, it shows the wrong thing, and so on. I used [this tutorial](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/gulp.html#browserify) as a basis, so it seems like it should work.

The relevant build step in my `gulpfile.js` is:

```
return browserify({
  basedir: '.',
  debug: mode === 'dev',
  entries: [`${paths.src}/app/${buildConfig.appFolder}/${buildConfig.appSrc}`],
  cache: {},
  packageCache: {},
})
  .plugin(tsify)
  .bundle()
  .pipe(source('app.js'))
  .pipe(gulp.dest(`${paths.dist}/app/${buildConfig.appFolder}`))
  .on('error', err => {
    console.error(err.toString());
    done(err);
  });
```

And `tsconfig.json` is:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": ["es2018", "dom"],
    "target": "es2015",
    "jsx": "react",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "diagnostics": true,
    "types": [
      "react",
      "react-dom",
      "lodash"
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the compiler options:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
     "sourceMap": true,
     "inlineSources": true
  }
}
```

`"sourceMap": true` tells typescript to emit source maps. `"inlineSources": true` tells it to embed the typescript source within the source map itself.

If this still doesn't work, you could try using `"inlineSourceMap": true` (in conjunction with `inlineSources`) which causes the sourcemaps to actually be inlined within the emitted javascript (best to make sure production builds disable this to avoid bloating your final bundles)

Whether this will work with your exact gulp / browserify setup I'm unsure. That tutorial you linked mentions adding:

```
var sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');

....
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init({loadMaps: true}))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./'))
```

Which may be worth a try as well, though this appeared to be in relation to uglify, https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/gulp.html#uglify

ref: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html

Overall I've found sourcemaps with typescript to be frustrating - even with a correct setup I still find occasionally I get poor breakpoint / code stepping behavior, though it has definitely been improving over the years.

As a general tip I find having third party dependencies split off to a separate bundle, and then blackboxing this in the chrome dev tools to help, as it avoids stepping into library code for promises, observables, etc

Comment: Thanks - unfortunately no dice. To me it almost undoes the benefits of typescript if you can't step through your code any more :( BTW I have also tried it with the lines you suggest ({loadMaps: true} etc), and that didn't help either. Very frustrating. Appreciate your effort to help though.

Comment: One other thing that may help, when the browser is being uncooperative about stepping through, I find that "debugger" statements still cause it to break at the appropriate points